# Ajax get undefined List from restful API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried search first but no fix.
here is my jQuery code.

```js
var rootUrl = "http://" + window.location.host + "/Blog/rest/posts";
var allPosts = function() {
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : rootUrl,
  dataType : "json",
  success : renderAllPosts
 });
};

var renderAllPosts = function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(index, post) {
  alert(data); // returns [object Object]
  alert(post); // returns [object Object],[object Object]
  $('#allPosts').append(
    '<a href=posts/' + post.ID + '><h3 id="animation_style">'
      + post.title + '</h3></a><hr>');

 });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
// alert(window.location.host);
 allPosts();
});
```

Here is the data that rootUrl returns
[image]

When I only have one record in database it works fine... 
I have no idea why alert(post) returns two objects. I think it should be alert(data) returns two objects.

keep getting this
[image]

Comment: I tried $.each(data.data, function(index, post) and $.each(data.dataList, function(index, post), not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data, has an attribute called postModel, you should change this:

```
var renderAllPosts = function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, post) {
        alert(data); // returns [object Object]
        alert(post);    // returns [object Object],[object Object]
        $('#allPosts').append('<a href=posts/' + post.ID + '><h3 id="animation_style">'+ post.title + '</h3></a><hr>');
    });
}
```

For:

```
var renderAllPosts = function(data) {
    $.each(data.postModel, function(index, post) {
        alert(data); // returns [object Object]
        alert(post);    // returns [object Object],[object Object]
        $('#allPosts').append('<a href=posts/' + post.ID + '><h3 id="animation_style">'+ post.title + '</h3></a><hr>');
    });
}
```

That way, you'll cycle through the array of posts

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. Could you explain why there is a postModel in the data please? Does Hibernate have anything to do with it? I did this before in college with JDBC code only and it was working perfectly.

Comment: I don't know why there's `postModel`, but in the picture you uploaded, showing the response, you can see it. You should check your posts method in your REST API